# Incorrect value returned by tkinter method canvas.winfo_width

Tags: python, tkinter

I've just started learning how to create a game with `tkinter`. I found it so difficult to find information for all the available methods in the module. This [website](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/) seemed comprehensive but was difficult to navigate to find relevant info for a specific method (for example `winfo_width`). I then tried to find the purpose of the method in question (`winfo_width`) by running an example. However, the returned value didn't make sense as shown below

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
>>> canvas.pack()
>>> rect = canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150, fill="red")
>>> print(canvas.winfo_width())
304  # should be 300, as specified in line 3
```

Could you please explain why the returned value was 304 instead of 300, and what is the best resource to find info for all available methods in the `tkinter`?

Comment: It includes the *highlightthickness* which is 2 in each side by default.

Comment: How on earth I would understand that without your explanation? Could you please recommend some resources on tkinter to me? Thanks

Comment: I refer to the website you mentioned in the question most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas has multiple options that affect its size. On my machine I get a size of 306, which represents the 300 pixels specified for the canvas, 0 pixels of borderwidth, and 3 pixels for `highlightthickness`. If you want the answer to be exactly 300, you need to explicitly set both the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to zero. Your system apparently has different defaults for `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` than my system does.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
```

The best resource for all of the options is the [tcl/tk manual pages](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.htm). The documentation there is the canonical documentation for the tk widgets.

It requires a slight mental translation from tcl to python, but the python docs ([Tkinter Life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver)) cover that.

From an interactive prompt you can use `help`. For example, `help(tk.Canvas)` will give you lots of information, though it's tedious to wade through it. You can also use the `configure` method to get a lost of all options and their current values:

```
>>> print("\n".join([str(item) for item in canvas.configure().items()]))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Due to my limited programming knowledge, the tcl/tk manual is *useless* for me. For example, when I clicked on the item `bell` (https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bell.htm), the display info didn't give any examples on how to use `bell`!

Comment: Thanks for the added info (`print("\n".join([str(item) for item in canvas.configure().items()]))`), Bryan.

Comment: @Nemo: the manual pages rarely give examples of how to use a command. Instead, they serve to document the behavior and all of the available options. You asked for info about all available methods, and the man pages provide exactly that information.

Comment: True, my bad for not articulately asking for a **user guide** on all tinker's available methods. Do you happen to know something like this (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/index.html) for tinker?